Nonetype error when trying to run a web scraping code
When I run the code for webscraping it gives me an error:
    published_date = job.find_next('span', class_='cm-post-date').text.strip()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'


It probably means that job.find_next did not find the element you were looking for. Does that answer your question?

@mkrieger1 Just probably? It definitely means that.

@mkrieger1 When you hear hoofbeats, think horses, not zebras. This is clearly Beautiful Soup.

Does this answer your question? Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?
